# How do I make sort json object values in discord.js code block?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, discord.js

My current code:

```js
const fetch = require("node-fetch");    
const data = await fetch(
      `https://pokemonrevolution.net/spawns/land_spawns.json`
    ).then((res) => res.json());

    const filterFromPoke = data.filter((p) => p.Pokemon === "Pikachu");

    const filteredMap = filterFromPoke
      .map((s) =>
        `${s.Map}        Land                    Tier ${s.Tier}  ${s.MinLVL}-${s.MaxLVL}    ${s.MemberOnly}     ${s.Item}`
          .replace("null", "-")
          .replace("false", "No")
          .replace("true", "Yes")
      )
      .reduce((spw, spnxt) => {
        spw = spw + "\n";
        return spw + spnxt;
      });

    const mssg = `\`\`\`md\n#Map                               Area    Rarity    Levels    MS    Time    Item\n${filteredMap}\`\`\``;

message.channel.send(mssg);
```

Returns:
[Image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLQcH.png)

I want it to return something like this [click here](https://kyoyo.is-ne.at/uhbvTT.png)

Could someone please help me out to sort that clean like the example? Thanks

Comment: One thing you could do is get the maximum length of the strings in each column, add about 5, and then use `padEnd` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padEnd

Comment: Thank you, but that doesn't solve my issue :(

Comment: That's basically the whole code itself.

Comment: Hey @aetrnyx, could you tell me what was the reason you unaccepted my answer? I think it was a really helpful one.

Answer (score 1):

First, I thought that you could do it with embeds, but as Discord only displays three columns, so this one didn't work as expected. I'm just leaving it here, because if someone has only three columns max, it works fine.

```js
client.on('message', async (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;

  const res = await fetch('https://pokemonrevolution.net/spawns/land_spawns.json');
  const data = await res.json();
  const filteredData = data.filter((p) => p.Pokemon === 'Pikachu');
  const embed = new MessageEmbed().setTitle('Pokemons');

  const obj = { map: '', area: '', tier: '', levels: '', ms: '', item: '' };

  filteredData.forEach((spawn) => {
    obj.map += `\n${spawn.Map}`;
    obj.area += `\nLand`;
    obj.tier += `\n${spawn.Tier}`;
    obj.levels += `\n${spawn.MinLVL}-${spawn.MaxLVL}`;
    obj.ms += `\n${spawn.MemberOnly ? 'Yes' : 'No'}`;
    obj.item += `\n${spawn.Item ? spawn.Item : '-'}`;
  });

  embed.addFields(
    { name: '#Map', value: obj.map, inline: true },
    { name: 'Area', value: obj.area, inline: true },
    { name: 'Tier', value: obj.tier, inline: true },
    { name: 'Levels', value: obj.levels, inline: true },
    { name: 'MS', value: obj.ms, inline: true },
    { name: 'Item', value: obj.item, inline: true },
  );

  message.channel.send(embed);
});
```

The result looked like this:

[image]

Endothermic_Dragon's solution was a bit closer to what you wanted, so I made an improved version of theirs. You can find it below:

```js
client.on('message', async (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;

  const res = await fetch('https://pokemonrevolution.net/spawns/land_spawns.json');
  const data = await res.json();
  const filteredData = data.filter((p) => p.Pokemon === 'Pikachu');

  // number of empty characters between columns
  const padding = 3;

  const lengths = filteredData.reduce(
    (acc, curr) => {
      const level = `${curr.MinLVL}-${curr.MaxLVL}`;
      const tier = curr.Tier.toString();

      return {
        levels: level.length > acc.levels ? level.length : acc.levels,
        map: curr.Map.length > acc.map ? curr.Map.length : acc.map,
        memberOnly: curr.memberOnly ? 'Yes'.length : 'No'.length,
        tier: tier.length > acc.tier ? tier.length : acc.tier,
      };
    },
    {
      levels: 0,
      map: 0,
      memberOnly: 0,
      tier: 0,
    },
  );
  const header = [
    '#Map'.padEnd(lengths.map + padding),
    'Area'.padEnd('Area'.length + padding),
    'Rarity'.padEnd(lengths.tier + 'Tier '.length + padding),
    'Levels'.padEnd(lengths.levels + padding),
    'Members Only'.padEnd('Members Only'.length + padding),
    'Item',
  ].join('');

  const table = filteredData.map((d) => [
      d.Map.padEnd(lengths.map + padding),
      'Land'.padEnd('Land'.length + padding),
      `Tier ${`${d.Tier}`.padEnd(lengths.tier + padding)}`,
      `${d.MinLVL}-${d.MaxLVL}`.padEnd(lengths.levels + padding),
      `${d.MemberOnly ? 'Yes' : 'No'}`.padEnd('Members Only'.length + padding),
      d.Item ? d.Item : '-',
    ].join(''))
    .join('\n');

  message.channel.send(`\`\`\`md\n${header}\n${table}\`\`\``);
});
```

It seems to be working as expected:

[image]

If you want to fetch from another endpoint if the first one yield no results, you can use the following code. I've made a few other changes and tried to add comments too:

```js
function getDaytimeNames(daytime = []) {
  let names = ['M', 'D', 'N'];
  return daytime
    .reduce((acc, curr, i) => (curr ? [...acc, names[i]] : acc), [])
    .join('/');
}

async function fetchData(pokemon) {
  let res = await fetch('https://pokemonrevolution.net/spawns/land_spawns.json');
  let data = await res.json();
  let reducer = (area) => (acc, curr) => curr.Pokemon.toLowerCase() !== pokemon.toLowerCase()
    ? acc
    : [
        ...acc,
        {
          area,
          daytime: getDaytimeNames(curr.Daytime),
          item: curr.Item ? curr.Item : '-',
          levels: `${curr.MinLVL}-${curr.MaxLVL}`,
          map: curr.Map,
          memberOnly: `${curr.MemberOnly ? 'Yes' : 'No'}`,
          tier: `Tier ${curr.Tier}`,
        },
      ];
  let landReducer = reducer('Land');
  let filteredData = data.reduce(landReducer, []);

  if (filteredData.length > 0)
    return filteredData;

  let surfReducer = reducer('Surf');
  // If there was no filtered data from land_spawns, try surf_spawns
  res = await fetch('https://pokemonrevolution.net/spawns/surf_spawns.json');
  data = await res.json();
  filteredData = data.reduce(surfReducer, []);

  return filteredData;
}

function createTable(data, padding) {
  const addPadding = (str, length) => str.padEnd((length || str.length) + padding);
  const getMaxLengths = (acc, curr) => {
    const getLongest = (prop) => curr[prop].length > acc[prop] ? curr[prop].length : acc[prop];
    return {
      area: getLongest('area'),
      daytime: getLongest('daytime'),
      levels: getLongest('levels'),
      map: getLongest('map'),
      memberOnly: getLongest('memberOnly'),
      tier: getLongest('tier'),
    };
  };

  const lengths = data.reduce(getMaxLengths, {
    area: 0,
    daytime: 0,
    levels: 0,
    map: 0,
    memberOnly: 0,
    tier: 0,
  });

  const headers = [
    addPadding('#Map', lengths.map),
    addPadding('Area', lengths.area),
    addPadding('Daytime'),
    addPadding('Rarity', lengths.tier),
    addPadding('Levels', lengths.levels),
    addPadding('Members Only'),
    // No padding needed as it's the last column
    'Item',
  ].join('');

  const createRow = (d) => [
    addPadding(d.map, lengths.map),
    addPadding(d.area, lengths.area),
    addPadding(d.daytime, 'Daytime'.length),
    addPadding(d.tier, lengths.tier),
    addPadding(d.levels, lengths.levels),
    addPadding(d.memberOnly, 'Members Only'.length),
    d.item,
  ].join('');

  const table = data.map(createRow).join('\n');

  return `${headers}\n${table}`;
}

// Create an array of rows with a max length
// making sure it always has complete rows only
function chunkify(str, max) {
  let chunks = [];

  while (str.length > max) {
    let i = str.substr(0, max).lastIndexOf('\n');
    chunks.push(str.substr(0, i));
    str = str.substr(i + 1, str.length);
  }
  if (str.length > 0) {
    chunks.push(str);
  }
  return chunks;
}

client.on('message', async (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;

  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
  const pokemon = args[0];

  const data = await fetchData(pokemon);

  // Number of empty characters between columns
  const padding = 2;
  // Discord only allows a maximum of 2000 characters for content
  const maxLength = 1980;
  const table = createTable(data, padding);

  chunkify(table, maxLength)
    .forEach((chunk) => message.channel.send(`\`\`\`md\n${chunk}\`\`\``));
});
```

[image]

Comment: That was a great help! Thank you very much. Got a question, is there any way to fetch from two different endpoints of the same API?
Like, if it's not available in the previous API, then it will look on the [second api](https://pokemonrevolution.net/spawns/surf_spawns.json), along with that it will change the `Area` to `Surf` if it fetches from the second.

Comment: I've tried something [this](https://sourceb.in/ADuWDXVKkP) and this doesn't seem to be work.

Comment: I've updated my answer, it should work with both endpoints now.

Comment: `// Discord only allows a maximum of 2000 characters for content const maxLength = 1980;`
Would that be possible to increase that? Cause I believe some of them might have more characters, than that. Not sure, but I assume sending the message again like [this](https://kyoyo.is-ne.at/CFsRsh.png) could fix that issue?

Comment: If you try to send something over 2000 characters, it won't send the message and will throw an error instead. The amount of characters on your image is way over 2000 characters, you have to chop it up, that's why I added the `chunkify` function which sends it in two messages instead.

Comment: I've added daytime to the [code](https://sourceb.in/BVletVfHVi), and now I'm getting this [error](https://kyoyo.is-ne.at/K3mXiQ.png). Line 81 is basically the getLongest function.

Comment: I'll try to look into this but `daytime: curr.daytime,` should be `daytime: curr.Daytime,` as the API uses capitalised names. I've just updated the code.

Comment: Hello, I have got a question. Have you had filtered the Pokemon from this line?
`let reducer = (area) => (acc, curr) => curr.Pokemon.toLowerCase() !== pokemon.toLowerCase()`

Comment: Yes, I used a reducer to filter out those entries where the `Pokemon` field is not the same and to convert the API data for later in a single step.

Comment: Thanks, do you think it would be possible to add `||` and filter by both Map and Pokemon?

Comment: Sure, you can extend that but don't forget that it currently checks if the item's `Pokemon` property is not the same as the `pokemon` variable. So, depending on your requirements you will either need `||` or `&&`, but feel free to try it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
fetch(`https://pokemonrevolution.net/spawns/land_spawns.json`)
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then(data => data.filter((p) => p.Pokemon === "Pikachu"))
  .then(data => {
    var mapLength = 0,
      tierLength = 0,
      minLevelLength = 0,
      maxLevelLength = 0,
      memberOnlyLength = 0,
      itemLength = 0;
    data.forEach(dataPoint => {
      mapLength = (mapLength > dataPoint.Map.length) ? mapLength : dataPoint.Map.length;
      tierLength = (tierLength > dataPoint.Tier.toString().length) ? tierLength : dataPoint.Tier.toString().length;
      minLevelLength = (minLevelLength > dataPoint.MinLVL.toString().length) ? minLevelLength : dataPoint.MinLVL.toString().length;
      maxLevelLength = (maxLevelLength > dataPoint.MaxLVL.toString().length) ? maxLevelLength : dataPoint.MaxLVL.toString().length;

      if (dataPoint.MemberOnly) {
        memberOnlyLength = (memberOnlyLength > "Yes") ? memberOnlyLength : 3
      } else {
        memberOnlyLength = (memberOnlyLength > "No") ? memberOnlyLength : 2
      }
    })

    console.log(mapLength)
    console.log(tierLength)
    console.log(minLevelLength)
    console.log(maxLevelLength)
    console.log(memberOnlyLength)
    console.log(itemLength)

    data.map(dataPoint => {
      dataPoint.Map = dataPoint.Map.padEnd(mapLength + 5)
      dataPoint.Tier = dataPoint.Tier.toString().padEnd(tierLength + 5)
      dataPoint.MinLVL = dataPoint.MinLVL.toString().padEnd(minLevelLength + 5)
      dataPoint.MaxLVL = dataPoint.MaxLVL.toString().padEnd(maxLevelLength + 5)
      if (dataPoint.MemberOnly) {
        dataPoint.MemberOnly = "Yes".padEnd(memberOnlyLength + 5)
      } else {
        dataPoint.MemberOnly = "No".padEnd(memberOnlyLength + 5)
      }
      if (dataPoint.Item == null) {
        dataPoint.Item = "-"
      }
      return dataPoint
    })

    totalString = "#Map".padEnd(mapLength + 5) + "Area     " + "Rarity".padEnd(tierLength + 5) + "Min LVL".padEnd(minLevelLength + 5) + "Max LVL".padEnd(maxLevelLength + 5) + "Members Only".padEnd(memberOnlyLength + 5) + "Item" + "\n";
    data.forEach(dataPoint => {
      totalString += [dataPoint.Map, "Land     ", "Tier " + dataPoint.Tier, dataPoint.MinLVL, dataPoint.MaxLVL, dataPoint.MemberOnly, dataPoint.Item].join('') + "\n"
    })
    console.log(totalString)
  })
```

Note that the JS won't work here because of CORS, but it should work when you actually do it. Here's a screenshot of it working:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for that. But sadly it ain't working either. [Image link](https://kyoyo.is-ne.at/NakxpP.png)