# Discord.js Table with embed maybe?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, embed

I just want to make a table according to this. But could not find any code like this. Anyone know?

[image]

Comment: The image you provided did not show anything.. perhaps you sent a wrong image link?

Comment: Image is the table that i wanted to do actually.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make sort json object values in discord.js code block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66736892/how-do-i-make-sort-json-object-values-in-discord-js-code-block)

Answer (score 1):

tables **aren't supported** in embed messages, but you can make something **similar** with [embed fields](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/typedef/EmbedField).

**Note**: Using the [inline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66485287/how-to-make-a-discord-embed-with-only-2-columns) option may be **helpful**.

Comment: How about only table like this? I mean without embed is it possible?

Comment: Yes, you can use [text table](https://www.npmjs.com/package/text-table) or you can check [this conversation](https://www.reddit.com/r/Discord_Bots/comments/jrn4e1/i_made_a_table_builder_you_can_use_in_jsts_to/)